# Navigating through Sequence of DataFrames in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function which returns dataFrames val ,a sequence of three dataframes. How do I navigate through this val to print the dataframe content?

```
val dataFrames : Seq[(DataFrame,DataFrame,DataFrame)]=  <function-returned-value>
```

I have tried `foreach()`, but it throws below error.I understood the error, but couldn't figure out the correct syntax

```
dataFrames.foreach(x=>x.show())
```

> Message: :84: error: value show is not a member of (org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

```
dataFrames.foreach(x=>x.show())
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try foreach method? and this is a value by the way. Not a variable!

Comment: @Rani foreach is not working because you have Sequence of tuples of DataFrames, not just a sequence of DataFrames

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to print the content of a dataframe or how to loop through the sequence?

A dataframe is usually to big to print, the show method can be used to print the first X elements. So for example the following would print the first 100 rows

```
df.show(100)
```

You can always collect the dataframe and then print the rows one by one if you know it is small enough to fit into the driver.

As for looping through the sequence and tuple, you can do something like:

```
val dataFrames: Seq[(DataFrame,DataFrame,DataFrame)]
for {
    x <- dataFrames
} {
  x._1.show(100)
  x._2.show(100)
  x._3.show(100)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this has worked for me, How do I union all the data frames x._1 into a single one ?

Comment: @Rani did you mean this: 
`var df = null;
for {
    x <- dataFrames
} {
  if (df == null) df = x._1
  else { df = df.union(x._1) }
}`?